# Multiple startups on client

Tags: meteor

We're seeing very strange Meteor behavior. After a simple event hook is executed (which gathers info from a form, executes an insert and updates a Session variable), the client seems to startup again, redrawing the entire page. In effect, Meteor.startup is being executed more than once, even though the browser window is not being refreshed (or anything like that). Even stranger is the fact that we've made extremely similar apps, but they don't display this behavior at all. We cannot detect any significant differences between the different projects.

We're using Meteor version 0.6.4.1 (in all cases), both autopublish and insecure have been removed.

Playlist.html:

```
<body>
{{> addSong}}
{{> playlist}}
</body>

<template name="addSong">
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a song to the playlist!</legend>
        <div><input type="text" id="artist" /></div>
        <div><input type="text" id="title" /></div>
        <div><button type="submit" id="insertButton">Insert</button></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</template>

<template name="playlist">
<div>Votes left: {{votes}}</div>
<ul>
    {{#each songs}}
        <li>
    {{artist}} - {{title}} - {{score}}
    <button class="voteUp" mongo_id="{{_id}}">Vote up!</button>
    <button class="remove" mongo_id="{{_id}}">X</button>
</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

lib/common.coffee

```
@Songs = new Meteor.Collection "songs"

Songs.allow
    insert: (userID) ->
            true
    update: (userID) ->
            true
    remove: (userID) ->
            true
```

client/client.coffee

```
Meteor.subscribe "songs"

Template.playlist.songs = ->
  Songs.find {},{sort:{"score":-1}}

Template.playlist.votes = -> Session.get("votes")

Template.addSong.events
  'click #insertButton': (event,template) ->
    artist = template.find("#artist").value
    title = template.find("#title").value
    Songs.insert({"artist":artist,"title":title,"score":1})
    votes = Session.get("votes")
    Session.set "votes", votes+3
    return

Template.playlist.events
    'click .voteUp': (event,template) ->
        id = event.target.attributes.mongo_id.value
        Songs.update({_id:id},{$inc:{"score":1}})
    'click .remove': (event,template) ->
        id = event.target.attributes.mongo_id.value
        Songs.remove({_id:id})

Meteor.startup ->
    alert "Starting"
    Session.setDefault "votes", 0
```

server/server.coffee

```
Meteor.publish "songs", -> Songs.find({})
```

To replicate the weird behavior, just submit items on the form, this triggers a startup every time (verified in Chrome as well as Safari).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code on github, I can help to look at it, but with just your description, it's hard to say what the problem would be...

Answer (score 0):

OK. We've found out what the problem is. The `<form`> tag, in combination with a submit button caused the client to execute a HTTP POST, which cause the entire page to re-render.
It's a very subtle problem and quite hard to detect, but the lesson here is that you shouldn't use `<form`> tags unless you are absolutely certain. Some kind of mechanism/warning/documentation might be a good idea to prevent this from happening to other people.

Comment: You can use anything you want, just do a `event.preventDefault()`.